# Passing selected DropDownListFor value to Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Have a form where values are being passed into an Ajax script and then to the controller.  All manual entry ones work but anything in a dropdownlist doesn't seem to be passed back.

So for example:

```
<div style="display: table-row;">
    <div class="div-dd-label-text" , style="display: table-cell">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="div-dropdown-menu" , style="display: table-cell">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, (SelectList)ViewBag.NameTitle, "Please select a title", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "dropdown", id = "txtTitle" } })
    </div>
    <div class="div-val-cell" , style="display: table-cell">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="div-label-text" , style="display: table-cell">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Initials)
    </div>
    <div class="div-EditorFor" , style="display: table-cell">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Initials, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "div-form-control", id = "txtInitials" } })
    </div>
    <div class="div-val-cell" , style="display: table-cell">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Initials, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

the drop down list returns a list of titles:

and I capture them here when the user submits the form:

```
<script>
    var urlAction = "@Url.Content("~/Treeview/_NewEmpDetails")";
    function AjaxGoodRedirect(urlAction) {
        console.log(urlAction);
        var form = $("#myForm");
        form.validate();
        if (form.valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: urlAction,
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    Title: $("#txtTitle").val()
                    , Initials: $("#txtInitials").val()
```

That then hits this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _NewEmpDetails(NewEmp.First model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var sessionValues = new MySessionValues();
        sessionValues.Employee = model;
        Session["MySessionValues"] = sessionValues;
    }
    return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = ("/Treeview/_NewEmpSecond") }, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);  
}
```

Redirects to the next form

```
public ActionResult _NewEmpSecond()
{
    var sessionValues = Session["MySessionValues"] as MySessionValues;
    ViewBag.NameTitle = sessionValues.Employee.Title;
    ViewBag.Initials = sessionValues.Employee.Initials;       
    return PartialView();
}
```

Currently I set the `ViewBag` properties to be the values for debugging and while the initials has a value when entered the nameTitle doesn't and I can't work out why

I have this in the next form to display the values for now:

```
<div> Value check for Title: @ViewBag.NameTitle </div>
<div> Value check for Initials: @ViewBag.Initials </div>
```

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: You're missing "<" char? at div class="div-dropdown-menu"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an anonymous object composed of `htmlAttributes` to `DropDownListFor`. That's only for adding additional attributes when using `EditorFor`. For something like `DropDownListFor`, you just pass the anonymous object with the attributes:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, (SelectList)ViewBag.NameTitle, "Please select a title", new { @class = "dropdown", id = "txtTitle" })
```

As you have it now, the id is never being set on the select element, so the value isn't being selected by your JavaScript.